# if line begins with backslash in .txt file, do this

Tags: bash, macos, if-statement, sed

I am trying to get an if statement to work in bash that deals with lines beginning with `\` in a text file.

Something like this:

```
shasum -a 256 file_A\\\\\/\/.txt >> file_B.txt
if line begins with '\' in file_B.txt
    then sed 's/^/^.{65}  /; s/$/$/' that line in file_C.txt
else
    if line not begin with '\' in file_B.txt
        then sed 's/^/^.{64}  /; s/$/$/' that line in file_C.txt
    fi
fi
```

Contents of file_B.txt:

```
e5fba57b49dbe8196ee4fb4ddb407885582f88d8e52dfa6e5adb55204b589a88  /Users/1337/file_D.txt
\66590f18dafff57160770d885b090d54455e0fc900342d7752dc420405ae50f5  /Users/1337/file_A\\\\::.txt
```

Contents of file_C.txt:

```
/Users/1337/file_D.txt
/Users/1337/file_A\\::.txt
```

So, basically, the end result would look like this (this is inside file_C.txt):

```
^.{64}  /Users/1337/file_D.txt$
^.{65}  /Users/1337/file_A\\::.txt$
```

because line 2 began with a `\` and line 1 didn't.

If any of this is confusing, please don't hesitate asking me to clarify.

Mac OS X Yosemite, bash 3.2.57(1)-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
while read -r line; do
    n=64; [ ${line:0:1} == \\ ] && n=65
    echo "^.{$n}  ${line#*  }\$"
done <file_B.txt >file_C.txt
```

Comment: This works as expected. I replaced `n=64` and `n=65` with `n={64}` and `n={65}`. I'm just wondering, is this safe to run in all cases?

Comment: I'll add the braces into my answer (I'll probably put them in the echo). It's safe as far as I know. Can you give an example of a case you're worried about? Maybe test it a little!

Comment: Don't worry, I did test it out, I just wanted to be sure. I was just unsure if the lack of `'`s around `{64}` and `{65}` (like `n='{64}'`) would cause any issues.

Answer (score 1):

With sed

```
sed -E 's/(\\?)([^ ]*)(.*)/\^.64\1\3$/;s/4\\/5/' file_B.txt
```

In the first s command

`(\\?)([^ ]*)(.*)/`

Each line is split in 3 groups.
The first '\' is optionel.
The second is the hexadecimal data you don't need.
The third is the pseudo path

```
/\^.64\1\3$/
```

Each line is append by ^.64
The first and third groups are keep
Each line is prepend by $

In the second s command

```
s/4\\/5/
```

4\ is substitute by 5

Comment: I actually need it to append `^.{64}  ` or `^.{65}  ` and prepend `$`. How could I achieve that?