# Special characters AND literal characters in a text file in grep

Tags: bash, macos, unix, grep, wildcard

I am trying to have grep obey wildcards (`.{64}` and `.{65}`), beginning-of-line characters (`^`) and end-of-line characters (`$`) in a text file, while ignoring anything and everything else in between.

Contents of foo.txt:

```
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>$
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C$
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C [remain]$
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本$
^.{65}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\\F::$
```

Contents of bar.txt:

```
\456f0958a5fd779fd12a0b383cd6384a9916782655f9298865e087630b7dffc1  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\\\\F::
e7d616682023bf43930eb2c07590f259167b2b937097639975bf0838260be3f5  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
f978dda2d3be7e976ec25eee3a17f24a02af7386d163ae95c1fa48cdf75586a5  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/A
9f913e331f16e9bc5493a7c4c9480753351fd0098398e32c9b8d4870a63b65ea  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/B [LOL].dmg
14e024fd9762abda9958b57ff95c7e515deccbd162eda2e338993ca32d6f0474  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C
14e024fd9762abda9958b57ff95c7e515deccbd162eda2e338993ca32d6f0474  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C [remain]
791c3644922e627d46307b901017131ab06575bdcde708298e3a80f47af09d1f  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本
```

Here's the command I run:

```
grep -Ef foo.txt bar.txt
```

I want it to output this:

```
e7d616682023bf43930eb2c07590f259167b2b937097639975bf0838260be3f5  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
14e024fd9762abda9958b57ff95c7e515deccbd162eda2e338993ca32d6f0474  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C
14e024fd9762abda9958b57ff95c7e515deccbd162eda2e338993ca32d6f0474  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C [remain]
791c3644922e627d46307b901017131ab06575bdcde708298e3a80f47af09d1f  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本
\456f0958a5fd779fd12a0b383cd6384a9916782655f9298865e087630b7dffc1  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\\\\F::
```

But it outputs this instead:

```
14e024fd9762abda9958b57ff95c7e515deccbd162eda2e338993ca32d6f0474  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C
791c3644922e627d46307b901017131ab06575bdcde708298e3a80f47af09d1f  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本
```

Here is a list of how my files are named exactly:

```
\\F//
^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
A
B [LOL].dmg
C
C [remain]
D 日本
```

Is there any possible way for `grep` to output what I need? If not, are there any other methods (BBEdit/Notepad++, Text Mechanic, etc.) I can use to achieve the same effect?

---

### **EDIT:**

Changed the `...LOL[MAY...` line to:

```
#;."'&,\:`!*?$(){}[]<>|-=+% ~^^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
```

What I'll do is escape all offending characters using `sed`, add the wildcards, etc., feed foo.txt into `grep`, and then remove the escapes, wildcards, `^`s, and `$`.

So, here are the new contents of foo.txt:

```
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/#;."'&,\:`!*?$(){}[]<>|-=+% ~^^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C [remain]
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\\F::
```

I'll run these to escape the offending characters:

```
sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' foo.txt > baz.txt
sed -i '' 's/\$/\\\$/g' baz.txt
sed -i '' 's/\^/\\\^/g' baz.txt
```

What other characters do I need to escape? FYI, these are only being escaped for `grep`.

Next, I will use the following:

```
cat baz.txt | grep '\\\\' > backslashes.txt
cat baz.txt | grep -v '\\\\' > no_backslashes.txt
sed 's/^/^.{64}  /; s/$/$/' no_backslashes.txt > eggs.txt
sed 's/^/^.{65}  /; s/$/$/' backslashes.txt >> eggs.txt
```

Then I will run:

```
grep -Ef eggs.txt bar.txt
```

Afterwards, I will remove `^.{64}`, `^.{65}`, `$` (from the end only, to prevent filename records from being changed), and backslash escapes from baz.txt.

If any of this is confusing, please don't hesitate to ask me for clarification.

---

Mac OS X Yosemite, bash 3.2.57(1)-release, grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: After reading this, it looks like the following require escaping for grep to work correctly in my case: `#;."'&,\\`!*?$[]<>|-=+%~^` Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

There a couple of issues with your patterns:

1. No escaping certain characters which have special meaning in regex
2. Incorrect repeating pattern count

**Proposed Solution**:

```
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\^.\$\[E-frLOL\[MAY\[\]{}\(\)\?<NUL>$
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C$
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C \[remain\]$
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本$
^[\].{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\\{4}F::$
```

Escape the character class characters and quantifiers (`^$[]?`) and set repeating count correctly.

Comment: What is the list of characters/quantifiers I would have to escape? Is there a way I could automate escaping a mass amount of them without messing up the `^.{64/5}  ` or `$`?

Comment: That all depends, because there are lots of them, such as quantifiers (`?+*`), assertions (`^$`), groups (`()`), character classes (`[]`), etc. The easiest way to do it might be with a character class (eg. `[\[\]\^$()+*-]`), set it as a pattern group name and then use it wherever you need.

Comment: Sorry, I meant characters that I would have to escape in `grep` only. Unless that's what you meant...

Comment: If it's a literal string like `^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?` then you can use `\Q` ... `\E` to treat it as such (eg. `\Q^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?\E`). That'll do what you want without having to escape individually.

Comment: @leetbacoon I assume this is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602180/if-line-begins-with-backslash-in-txt-file-do-this)? If so, you should escape the regex characters in filenames (i.e. the ones you want treated as literal) *before* adding the regex stuff (which you want treated as special) to the beginning and end. Once they're both in the same string, separating them back out will be a mess.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what "regex" means. But anyway, yes, this is a followup. I will add escape characters, then append wildcards, `^`s and `$`s. In the end, I intend to then feed this through the `grep` command specified in the post.

Comment: And @I'L'I, I would add `\Q` and `\E`, but in a case where I have thousands of files, it might just be easier to use `sed` and add a backslash before each offending character, and then remove them when I'm done.

Comment: @leetbacoon: "regex" is "Regular Expression" abbreviated. The way in which you escape the special characters would likely depend on how many patterns you have I would imagine.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I updated the question. We're getting closer!

Answer (score 0):

It's gigantic, but this is what I did to get it to work:

Contents of foo.txt:

```
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/#;."'&,\:`!*?$(){}[]<>|-=+% ~^^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\\\\\\<-6 F 2->::
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C [remain]
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本
```

Contents of bar.txt:

```
\d4c88a749dcb8d8c09fd8e08e044f66d8d1d9cf9d191c62989697813d26a6b55  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/#;."'&,\\:`!*?$(){}[]<>|-=+% ~^^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
1ef8a2fb20e09e1866768d824289ffdbda12e565839fa7dda1fe12c4206e5759  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/@ss
\456f0958a5fd779fd12a0b383cd6384a9916782655f9298865e087630b7dffc1  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\\\\\\\\\\\\<-6 F 2->::
e7d616682023bf43930eb2c07590f259167b2b937097639975bf0838260be3f5  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
d96b11b464adc478e458943d080b5efac2e887a18ef4ae785d21506de5594ddc  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/A
9f913e331f16e9bc5493a7c4c9480753351fd0098398e32c9b8d4870a63b65ea  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/B [LOL].dmg
14e024fd9762abda9958b57ff95c7e515deccbd162eda2e338993ca32d6f0474  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C
14e024fd9762abda9958b57ff95c7e515deccbd162eda2e338993ca32d6f0474  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C [remain]
791c3644922e627d46307b901017131ab06575bdcde708298e3a80f47af09d1f  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本
```

Commands run:

```
$ sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' foo.txt > baz.txt
$ sed -i '' 's/\$/\\\$/g' baz.txt
$ sed -i '' 's/\^/\\\^/g' baz.txt
$ sed -i '' 's/\*/\\\*/g' baz.txt
$ sed -i '' 's/\?/\\\?/g' baz.txt
$ sed -i '' 's/\[/\\\[/g' baz.txt
$ sed -i '' 's/\]/\\\]/g' baz.txt
$ sed -i '' 's/(/\\\(/g' baz.txt
$ sed -i '' 's/)/\\\)/g' baz.txt
$ sed -i '' 's/}/\\\}/g' baz.txt
$ sed -i '' 's/{/\\\{/g' baz.txt
$ sed -i '' 's/\\\\/\\\\\{2}/g' baz.txt

$ cat foo.txt | grep '\\\\' > backslashes.txt
$ cat foo.txt | grep -v '\\\\' > no_backslashes.txt

$ sed 's/^/^.{64}  /; s/$/$/' no_backslashes.txt > qux.txt
$ sed 's/^/^.{65}  /; s/$/$/' backslashes.txt >> qux.txt
```

Contents of baz.txt:

```
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/#;."'&,\\{2}:`!\*\?\$\(\){}\[\]<>|-=+% ~\^\^.\$\[E-frLOL\[MAY\[\]{}\(\)\?<NUL>
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}<-6 F 2->::
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\^.\$\[E-frLOL\[MAY\[\]{}\(\)\?<NUL>
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C \[remain\]
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本
```

Contents of backslashes.txt:

```
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/#;."'&,\\{2}:`!\*\?\$\(\){}\[\]<>|-=+% ~\^\^.\$\[E-frLOL\[MAY\[\]{}\(\)\?<NUL>
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}<-6 F 2->::
```

Contents of no_backslashes:

```
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\^.\$\[E-frLOL\[MAY\[\]{}\(\)\?<NUL>
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C \[remain\]
/Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本
```

Contents of qux.txt:

```
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\^.\$\[E-frLOL\[MAY\[\]{}\(\)\?<NUL>$
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C$
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C \[remain\]$
^.{64}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本$
^.{65}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/#;."'&,\\{2}:`!\*\?\$\(\){}\[\]<>|-=+% ~\^\^.\$\[E-frLOL\[MAY\[\]{}\(\)\?<NUL>$
^.{65}  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}\\{2}<-6 F 2->::$
```

And now, finally, the command we've all been waiting for:

```
grep -Ef qux.txt bar.txt
```

Which outputs these lovely strings:

```
\d4c88a749dcb8d8c09fd8e08e044f66d8d1d9cf9d191c62989697813d26a6b55  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/#;."'&,\\:`!*?$(){}[]<>|-=+% ~^^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
\456f0958a5fd779fd12a0b383cd6384a9916782655f9298865e087630b7dffc1  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/\\\\\\\\\\\\<-6 F 2->::
e7d616682023bf43930eb2c07590f259167b2b937097639975bf0838260be3f5  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
14e024fd9762abda9958b57ff95c7e515deccbd162eda2e338993ca32d6f0474  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C
14e024fd9762abda9958b57ff95c7e515deccbd162eda2e338993ca32d6f0474  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/C [remain]
791c3644922e627d46307b901017131ab06575bdcde708298e3a80f47af09d1f  /Users/1337/Test Hash Folder/D 日本
```

Thank you all for your help!